# Can a targetted Dispel Magic end a spell with a duration of concentration?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, targeting, concentration

There are only a handful of spells with a duration of concentration.

While these spells are active, can the caster be subject to a Targeted version of *Dispel Magic* that does not aim at a spell, but rather the creature (presumably with the intention of ending all spells on that creature). Ostensibly, is the Concentration spell considered to be 'on' the caster?

For example, the *Implosion* spell has a duration of Concentration, which suggests that the caster is actively maintaining a magical effect (which they're using to smush others into goo). Given that others may be averse to being smushed into goo, could another character target the caster of *Implosion* with *Dispel Magic* to end that spell along with any other beneficial spells that the caster may've set up?

Comment: "There are only a handful of spells with a duration of concentration" - me, playing a druid in 5e, cries inside

Comment: @PixelMaster I feel you, but the simple act of expanding the Concentration mechanic in 5e was easily one of the best things they did to make it fun for diverse parties.

Comment: @PixelMaster Hey, y'all get to concentrate on things *for free*.  In 3.5, that's your action every round. In all seriousness, though, Pyrotechnical has the right of it.

Comment: Not sure where you get the idea that there are only a handful of spells with a duration of concentration, when there are well over a hundred.

Comment: Also, your best bet in such a situation is to just cast a damage dealing spell instead of Dispel Magic, as that would force the concentrating caster to make a Concentration check (DC = 10+damage dealt) or lose the spell.

Comment: @YopiLapi WotC alone published, like, 2,500 unique spells for *3.5* inclusive—even if 200 of those have a duration of Concentration, that's only a *comparative* handful. `:-)` Also, it's possible for a caster to've prepared no damage-dealing spells—in such a case, a wizard would probably prefer to use *dispel magic* instead of attacking the enemy with a crossbow, dagger, or staff.

Comment: @YopiLapi this site has a spell filter for all of the SRD spells: http://www.d20srd.org/extras/d20spellfilter/ and a quick comparison of those spells with a Duration: Concentration versus All Spells quickly reveals how small a subset that is.

Answer (score 2):

**No. But also maybe.**

[*Dispel magic,*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dispelMagic.htm) when targeting a creature, potentially affects each spell currently in effect on that creature. A spell like *implosion,* however, doesn't affect the caster- it affects the **target of the spell.** Although the caster does keep the spell going through concentration, I could find nothing describing concentration in and of itself as a magical effect- and thus you can't dispel your target's concentration.  This makes sense; concentration is a skill, not a spell or spell-like ability, and you shouldn't be able to dispel it anymore than you could use *dispel magic* on someone's Listen check.  What's more, [*implosion*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/implosion.htm) in particular mentions the effect it has on its target is instantaneous and not dispellable.

That said, casting a spell that distracts the caster in a non-damaging way does have the potential to [force a concentration check.](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/concentration.htm)  It's entirely possible that casting *dispel magic,* while not dispelling the spell the target is concentrating on, will still cause them to lose concentration and drop the spell anyway. And of course, any concentration spell affecting the target is fair game.